# How to push to a Form Array([]) in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, angular-reactive-forms

I have dynamic checkbox that get data from API, following is `html` file

```
<form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="submit()">
  <label formArrayName="summons" *ngFor="let order of form.controls.summons.controls; let i = index">
    <input type="checkbox" [formControlName]="i">
    {{summons[i].name}}
  </label>

  <div *ngIf="!form.valid">At least one order must be selected</div>
  <br>
  <button [disabled]="!form.valid">submit</button>
</form>
```

Following is the typescript file:

```
interface Item {
  offenceType4: string;
  permSpeed: string;
  actSpeed: string;
  itemAttributes: ItemAttributes;
  offenceLoc: string;
  itemNo: string;
  summonDate: string;
  distCode: string;
  summonType: string;
  hbtlOffndr: string;
  itemAmount: number;
  itemAttributesCount: number;
  summonAmt: string;
  offenceType1: string;
  offenceCode1: string;
  offenceType2: string;
  offenceCode2: string;
  offenceType3: string;
  category: string;
  offenceCode3: string;
  offenceCode4: string;
  respCode: string;
}

interface ItemAttributes {
  attribute5: string;
  attribute4: string;
  attribute7: string;
  attribute6: string;
  attribute1: string;
  attribute3: string;
  attribute2: string;

}
  interface RootObject {
  items: Item[];
  status: Status;
  additionalProperties: AdditionalProperties;
  metadata: Metadata;
}

export class InquiryResponseMultiselectComponent implements OnInit {
  form: FormGroup;
  summons = [];
  data: any[];

  constructor(
    private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
    private inquiryService: InquiryService
  ) {
    this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
      summons: new FormArray([], minSelectedCheckboxes(1)),
    });

     this.getSummon().subscribe(summons => {
      this.summons = summons;
      this.addCheckboxes();
    });
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getSummon();
  }

  getSummon() {
    return this.inquiryService.getData().pipe(map((item: RootObject) => 
  item.items)) ;
  }

  addCheckboxes() {
    this.summons.map(i => {
    const control = new FormControl();
    const formArray = this.form.controls.summons as FormArray;
    formArray.push(control);
    });
  }
```

Im getting response from API to dynamic my checkbox,then, I need to push the new control onto `summons FormArray`, but Im getting error which

> core.js:9110 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

if I not doing mapping which something like this:

```
  addCheckboxes() {
      const control = new FormControl();
      const formArray = this.form.controls.summons as FormArray;
      formArray.push(control);
  }
```

I will get default `formControl` length equal to 1, which something that i dont want, need advice and guide how do I solve this,

Comment: 1) You may use `form.invalid` instead of `!form.valid` 2) can't you wait for the server response before initializing the form, i.e. put the `formBuilder` inside the `subscribe` ?

Comment: @Random I dont get why to put the `formBuilder` inside `subscribe` can explain more ?

Comment: I made an answer to explain it

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using formbuilder no need to initialize formarray using FormArray instead use formbuilder api

```
   this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
      summons: this.formBuilder.array([]),
    });
```

Example:https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-boxw51

Comment: try to modify but got error **Argument of type 'FormControl[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'AbstractControl'**.

Comment: @hafizi no need to modify that method try the update one

Comment: still got same error @chellapan, btw im using this tutorial https://coryrylan.com/blog/creating-a-dynamic-checkbox-list-in-angular

Comment: Can you create stackblitz?

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7ckpqs?file=src%2Fassets%2Ftest.json, i had create one, @Chellappan

Answer (score 0):

Here, you init the form before receiving the data, so you are trying to change something that already exists, which is harder than making it from sratch.
To do so, you may init your form *inside* the subscribe, where you know what elements should your array contain.

```
  constructor(
    private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
    private inquiryService: InquiryService
  ) {

    this.inquiryService.getData().subscribe((receivedSummons: RootObject[]) => {
      this.summons = receivedSummons[0].data;

      let formControls = this.summons.items.map((summon, index) => {
        return new FormControl(index === 0);
      });
      this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
        summons: new FormArray(formControls),
      });
      this.addCheckboxes();
    });
  }
```

Doing so make you add a condition (`*ngIf`) at the beginning of your html form, to avoid an error while trying to access your form which is not yet initialized:

```
<form *ngIf="form" [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="submit()">
  <label formArrayName="summons" *ngFor="let order of form.controls.summons.controls; let i = index">
    <input type="checkbox" [formControlName]="i">
    {{summons[i].name}}
  </label>

  <div *ngIf="!form.valid">At least one order must be selected</div>
  <br>
  <button [disabled]="!form.valid">submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: placed receivedSummons in new FormArray, I got error for that, Argument of type item[] is not assignable to parameter of type AbstractControl..

Comment: im using this tutorial for reference.. https://coryrylan.com/blog/creating-a-dynamic-checkbox-list-in-angular

Comment: @hafizi indeed, you have to map your items into a `new FormControl`. Please see my edited answer (inside the `subscribe`)

Comment: still got error, btw i had create demo using stackblitz, can you look onto it, https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7ckpqs?file=src%2Fassets%2Ftest.json @Random

Comment: @hafizi I made it work. Typings is the key. The server response is `RootObject[]`, so the item list is in `receivedSummons[0].data.items`